# How to dynamically go over fields of objects and get a specific reference to field?

Tags: apex

I have a String[] of objects, that I want to go over, and look for all the fields that are lookup (related to/referenceto) 'Asset'. I want this, so in the future, if we add new fields, I don't need to change my code.

- just a custom_label that will hold the developer_name of the object to add to the search.

my code is failing

```
public with sharing class TestBrowseObjects {
    public TestBrowseObjects() {
        // Make the describe call
        String [] types = new String[]{'Case', 'Asset_Modules__c','Asset_History__c'};

        Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);


        // For each returned result, get some info
        for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = res.fields.getMap();
            // go over the field map, look for reference to 'Asset'
            for( String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet() ) {
                Schema.SObjectField field = fieldMap.get( fieldName );
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();
                Schema.SObjectType reference = fieldDescribe.getReferenceTo();
                if ( reference.getDescribe().getName() == 'Asset')
                {
                   system.debug('fieldDescribe.referenceto == ' + fieldDescribe.referenceto);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Schema.DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo()` returns a `List <Schema.sObjectType>`, because some lookup fields are polymorphic (such as, for example, `Task.WhoId`).

You'd need to add a loop to iterate over the return value and call `getDescribe().getName()` on each.

For reference to others, the updated median for loop:

```
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = res.fields.getMap();
            for( String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet() ) {
                Schema.SObjectField field = fieldMap.get( fieldName );
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = field.getDescribe();
                List <Schema.SObjectType> fieldsList = fieldDescribe.getReferenceTo();
                for (schema.SObjectType fieldRef : fieldslist )
                {
                    if ( fieldRef.getDescribe().getName() == 'Asset')
                    {
                       system.debug('fieldDescribe.referenceto == ' + fieldDescribe.referenceto);
                    }
                }
            }
```